# Subtraction difference between two lists

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have the following queryset:

```
Iva_total= {'Iva a debito': [0, 0, 0, 0, 44.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}

Ricavi_total= {'Ricavi': [0, 0, 0, 0, 200.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

I want to do the difference between two list() `Ricavi_total` and `Iva_total` to obtain the following result:

```
Difference = {'Difference': [0, 0, 0, 0, 156.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

**EDITS**

My queryset are given by the following code:

```
Ricavi_total={'Ricavi Lordi': [sum(t) for t in zip(*ricavi.values())],}
Iva_total={'Ricavi Lordi': [sum(t) for t in zip(*iva.values())],}
```

Comment: when you say "difference" you mean the subtraction from one to another, right?

Comment: yep exactly, substraction operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are going to use `zip()` in order to subtract the list like:

```
list1 = Iva_total.get('Iva a debito')
list2 = Ricavi_total.get('Ricavi')

list_diff = [num2-num1 for (num1, num2) in zip(list1, list2)]

Difference = {}
Difference['Difference'] = list_diff

print(Difference)          # You will get what you want
```

Comment: yuour code give me the following error: builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Comment: I have updated mu quesition with more details, I hope that help you

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {'Difference': []}
iva_scores = Iva_total['Iva a debito']
ric_scores = Ricavi_total['Ricavi']

for i in range(len(iva_scores)):
    data['Difference'].append(abs(iva_scores[i] - ric_scores[i]))

print(data)
```

Please use the above snippet to find the differences.